# Can I overlay an image or JPanel containing an image that spans over two different JLists and be transparent?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, overlay, jlist

I have two different JLists and I want the user to be able to select an item in one and drag from that item in the first JList to another item in another JList. Then when the drag is complete, I want an arrow to be displayed from the first item to the second item.

Is there a way I can overlay an image or an image inside a JPanel on top of two different JLists and be transparent so that I can always see all JList content around the arrow image?

Comment: maybe official Oracle tutorial with working code example [Demo - ChooseDropAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dropactiondemo.html) can be good start point

Comment: See also [*The Glass Pane*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane).

Comment: You may consider taking a look at [this](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/05/my-drag-image-is-better-than-yours.html)

Comment: @mKorbel That does not address the question. I have have drag and drop working. I want to be able to visually show an arrow on top of two JLists so as to show an item in one list targeting an item in another list, but not necessarily any drag and drop at this point. Once the action is confirmed after targeting, then an action would be done. Thanks though.